# SQL Limit clause - vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, limit, command-text

I've been trying to find a solution to my query regarding the LIMIT Clause, here's my code,

```
    "SELECT * FROM tbl_student WHERE s_grade='" & grade.Text & "' AND s_status='Validated' ORDER BY s_id_no ASC LIMIT 10"
```

I was wondering if could do,

```
    "SELECT * FROM tbl_student WHERE s_grade='" & grade.Text & "' AND s_status='Validated' ORDER BY s_id_no ASC LIMIT='" & txt_limit.Text & "'"
```

Getting the limit value based on my selection which contains the limit, but failed to do so, i get this syntax error.

Comment: dont use `=` sign with limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `LIMIT='" & txt_limit.Text & "'` to `LIMIT " & txt_limit.Text & "`

Two corrections
  **1.)** `LIMIT=`: `=` is invalid for LIMIT clause
  **2.)** `'" & txt_limit.Text & "'`: You're concatenating it as string because
       you've used `''` the command text produce `LIMIT '10'`, so you should avoid it `''`

Comment: well that did the trick and also thanks for the explanation, now I know.

Comment: @LeoElvinLee **I strongly recommend to use  [parameterized SQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i)**

Answer (score 1):

`=` sign not use with LIMIT
try this

```
 "SELECT * FROM tbl_student WHERE s_grade='" & grade.Text & "' AND
 s_status='Validated' ORDER BY s_id_no ASC LIMIT " & txt_limit.Text & ";
```